# Can I overwrite a single byte in AT26DF081A Flash / SST25VF080B Flash?

Tags: flash

Is there any method to rewrite a single byte memory without erasing 4KB block?
I am keeping address table in one 4KB block.I need to update adresses occasionally.
Do I have to copy all addresses to RAM for modifying one address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: No.

What you have to do depends a lot on 1) How big is your data? 2) How often does it change? 3) What endurance do you require from the flash?

Answer (score 0):

you can over-write a single byte, but you can only write zeroes over ones, not ones over zeroes. to make ones you need to erase the block.

Answer (score 0):

To change bits from binary value 0 to binary value 1, an erase has to happen. So, sector erase is mandatory.

1. You can check whether the data to be written needs any bits to change state from 0 to 1. If not, (rarely) you can still proceed with normal write.
2. What is the address table size? Depending on the table size you may have multiple slots of memory in the 4 kB address space. Say for example upto `15(16-1)` tables if the address table is less than 256 bytes. The last block is for you to indicate which table block has the valid value. Once all the tables are used, time to perform sector erase and a reset to the logic
3. Depending on the erase life cycle allowed by the device and the worst case predicted write cycles, you can decide whether to invest time into the extra logic burden or to just go ahead with simple erase each time

Comment: I think you made a typo on your 1st line. An erase changes bit from 0 to 1, not 1 to 0.

Comment: @brhans thank you.